# Bluetooth Connection and Fileshaing

Tags: bluetooth, tracking, file-sharing

Is it possible to track bluetooth connections that are connected to eachother? and if yes, is it possible to see that they're sharing files/sending data with bluetooth?

It is for a personal chat program, that me and my friends are working on in C#.

Answer (score 0):

The Bluetooth devices and related status can be found using APIs of `Windows.Devices.Enumeration namespace` that are available for C#. They shall help in getting general information about devices connected to or discoverable by the system. It shall help in finding devices internally connected to the system, externally connected, or nearby over wireless or networking protocols and get information about them. The `DeviceWatcher` in turn shall help in finding and receiving updates for devices (like getting notifications when devices get added, connected, disconnected, change online status, or change other properties.)